# CLion configurations OSX

Tags: c#, configuration, cmake, clion

Just installed CLion because I want to learn C#. I am having some issues with the configuration and cannot find a solution. I have attached a image with problems. I cannot figure out why it is complaining about CMake since this should be installed along with CLion. Hope You can help.

Thx in advance

[image: Screenshot from CLion]

Answer (score 0):

CLion is for C++. If you want to learn C#, then use Xamarin Studio or Project Rider from JetBrains (Rider is in EAP and it does not work properly for me right now).